# Dictionary generated from 2 lists not doing what I want

Tags: python, dictionary, user-input

My problem is this, when given any input (correctly formatted) the dictionary `dancer_placings` is not correctly generated based on my code. An input of 1 dancer, with number 1, 2 dances, named foo and bar, the dictionary `dancer_placings` is `{'1': {'bar': 0}}`, when I want it to be `{'1': {'foo': 0},{'bar': 0}}`

I have obviously made a mistake, so how can I fix my code so that it does what I intend it to do?

Here is my code:

```
print("Welcome to Highland Scrutineer")

dancers = []
dances = []
dancer_placings = {}

dancers = []
dancer_num = int(input("How many dancers were there?: "))
while len(dancers) + 1 <= dancer_num:
    dancers.append(input("What was the number of the dancer? "))

print("The list of dancers is:")
for dancer in dancers:
    print(dancer)

dances = []
dance_num = int(input("How many dances did these dancers compete in? "))

while len(dances) + 1 <= dance_num:
    dances.append(input("What was the name of the dance? "))

print("The list of dances is:")
for dance in dances:
    print(dance)

for dancer in dancers:
    for dance in dances:
        dancer_placings.update({dancer:{}})
        dancer_placings[dancer].update({dance:0})

print(dancer_placings)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a few problems, but I'll just address the ones to make your use case work:

1. You're overwriting the dancerplacings every time:
   dancer_placings.update({dancer:{}})

That's not necessary. That should be up an indentation level.

2. You are currently creating a tuple, which is immutable. You'll need to use a list.

Try this:

```
print("Welcome to Highland Scrutineer")

dancers = []
dances = []
dancer_placings = {}

dancers = []
dancer_num = int(input("How many dancers were there?: "))
while len(dancers) + 1 <= dancer_num:
    dancers.append(input("What was the number of the dancer? "))

print("The list of dancers is:")
for dancer in dancers:
    print(dancer)

dances = []
dance_num = int(input("How many dances did these dancers compete in? "))

while len(dances) + 1 <= dance_num:
    dances.append(input("What was the name of the dance? "))

print("The list of dances is:")
for dance in dances:
    print(dance)

for dancer in dancers:
    dancer_placings[dancer] = []
    for dance in dances:
        dancer_placings[dancer].append({dance:0})

print(dancer_placings)
```

---

Thus, this results in the following output:

```
user-macbookpro2:~ user$ python test.py

Welcome to Highland Scrutineer

How many dancers were there?: 1

What was the number of the dancer? 1

The list of dancers is:

1

How many dances did these dancers compete in? 2

What was the name of the dance? 'foo'

What was the name of the dance? 'bar'

The list of dances is:

foo

bar

{1: [{'foo': 0}, {'bar': 0}]}
```

---

That appears to be your desired answer!

Comment: Thanks for the help! What problems do you think my code has that I need to address? I know implementing functions and maybe classes would help with the structure of my code, right now this is a proof-of-concept to see if this is a reasonable project for me.

Comment: The biggest suggestions would be to address edge cases, for example if you put in 0 dancers, it stills goes on to ask you questions.

Comment: Definitely something I would have forgotten! Anything else?

Comment: For any place that you are expecting a string, such as the "What was the name of the dance" question, I'd use `raw_input` instead of `input`. This allows you to put in a string as the end-user without needing to put quotes around it!

This is a good proof of concept! :)

p.s. if you're using python 3.0 (i'm not!), raw_input is gone, so you'll need to do `eval(input("question"))` instead of `raw_input("question")`

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are overwriting the values for dancer_placings for each dance.  A minor adjustment should return the results that you are seeking:

```
for dancer in dancers:
    dancer_placings.update({dancer: {}})
for dance in dances:
    dancer_placings[dancer].update({dance: 0})
```

I ran it through a quick scratch test and this was the result:

```
{'1': {'bar': 0, 'foo': 0}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The bit of code in question here is this:

```
for dancer in dancers:
    for dance in dances:
        dancer_placings.update({dancer:{}})
        dancer_placings[dancer].update({dance:0})
```

As it is written now, each iteration through dancers will have a loop through each dance. However, the statement `dancer_placings.update({dancer:{}})` will "clear out" the value of the current dancer at each iteration of the inner loop. Thus only the last inner iteration "sticks".

What you want is something like this:

```
for dancer in dancers:
    dancer_placings.update({dancer:{}})
    for dance in dances:    
        dancer_placings[dancer].update({dance:0})
```

Which would create an empty dictionary for each dancer in the outer loop, and update the dances in the inner loop.

So this would produce (notice that dictionary keys do not have a distinct ordering):

```
Welcome to Highland Scrutineer
How many dancers were there?: 3
What was the number of the dancer? 1
What was the number of the dancer? 2
What was the number of the dancer? 3
The list of dancers is:
1
2
3
How many dances did these dancers compete in? 4
What was the name of the dance? a
What was the name of the dance? b
What was the name of the dance? c
What was the name of the dance? d
The list of dances is:
a
b
c
d
{'1': {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'd': 0, 'c': 0}, '3': {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'd': 0, 'c': 0}, '2': {'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'd': 0, 'c': 0}}
```